# Visual Studio Community 2013 Apache Server (PHP)

Tags: php, apache, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to run an Apache server with "VS Community 2013" on Windows 8.1 to run PHP scripts? I have got Xammp and Sublime Text 3 for PHP programming, but I would like to code with VS. I have tried it with IIS Express, but for some reason is it not working. I guess, I need an Apache Server to run PHP properly. Is it possible to configure IIS rather Apache to run with VS?

Answer (score 1):

Apache is not associated with, nor bundled alongside, VS2013. You don't need Apache specifcally, or IIS specifically, you just need a server daemon that has a PHP handler, so either will do and there's documentation on how to set up PHP with either, so just pick whichever one you want.

Write your scripts in whatever IDE you want - the code writing aspect of a PHP site is not related to how you *serve* that code. Both Apache and IIS will let you do that just fine (but with very different configurations, obviously, because they're completely different projects)